# How to perform AsyncTask for checking internet connection

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the following code, and what I'm trying to do is to programmatically check if there is an internet connection or not.
Since I'm getting a **NetworkOnMainThreadException**, and have been advised to use AsyncTask.
I want to perform network operation on `hasActiveInternetConnection(Context context)`and return true if connected to a network, else false .
**How do I do this using AsyncTask?**

```
 public class NetworkUtil extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        Context context;

        public NetworkUtil(Context context){
            this.context = context;
         }

    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        if (new CheckNetwork(context).isNetworkAvailable()) 
        {
             try {
                 HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection());
                 urlc.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Test");
                 urlc.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                 urlc.setConnectTimeout(1500); 
                 urlc.connect();
                 boolean url= (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200);
                 String str = String.valueOf(url);
                 return str;
             } catch (IOException e) {

             }
         } 


            // your get/post related code..like HttpPost = new HttpPost(url);
         else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "no internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: you want to check if you have connection or not to do staff ?
or you want to wait until you have internet connection to do staff ?

Comment: @ahmed I want to just check internet connection and if connection exist then i want to return true !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There is no way to get an Internet connexion state, you will always have the network connection state.
```

But I found a pretty nice answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts): you send a request to google.com !! :) you can also try to ping to google by unix commandes if you want !!

here the guy is using a thread , and waiting a little bit for the answer, then returning a boolean . you do your staff in the handler . this is his code :

```
public static void isNetworkAvailable(final Handler handler, final int timeout) {
    // ask fo message '0' (not connected) or '1' (connected) on 'handler'
    // the answer must be send before before within the 'timeout' (in milliseconds)

    new Thread() {
        private boolean responded = false;   
        @Override
        public void run() { 
            // set 'responded' to TRUE if is able to connect with google mobile (responds fast) 
            new Thread() {      
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    HttpGet requestForTest = new HttpGet("http://m.google.com");
                    try {
                        new DefaultHttpClient().execute(requestForTest); // can last...
                        responded = true;
                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                } 
            }.start();

            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(!responded && (waited < timeout)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(!responded ) { 
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException e) {} // do nothing 
            finally { 
                if (!responded) { handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); } 
                else { handler.sendEmptyMessage(1); }
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

Then, I define the handler:

```
Handler h = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        if (msg.what != 1) { // code if not connected

        } else { // code if connected

        }   
    }
};
```

...and launch the test:

```
isNetworkAvailable(h,2000); // get the answser within 2000 ms
```

Comment: Working well ! Will just confirm in a moment if this is working well ! ty for the code btw :)

Comment: Worked flawlessly ty :)

Answer (score 5):

use this class for checking internet connectivity...

```
public class CheckNetwork {
private Context context;

public CheckNetwork(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
            .getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

}

then.....

use the this ASynTask for httppost.

```
public class NetworkUtil extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    if (new CheckNetwork(YourActivity.this).isNetworkAvailable()) {
        // your get/post related code..like HttpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    } else {
        // No Internet 
        // Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "no internet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much...I have updated my code above...Could you please confirm If I'm going on the right way . And how do i get that  return str; value in another class ? ty !

Comment: u r going right just do two things...
1 . While calling the NetworkUtil class send YourActivity.this not getApplicationContext().

2. make the str variable as class variable, bu declaring ..
       **public static String str;**

Comment: and also write... 
**dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.show();** in onPreExecute() method

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Google.com might one day go down ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `AsyncTask` should look like this:

```
 private class NetworkUtilTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
    Context context;

    public NetworkUtilTask(Context context){
        this.context = context;
     }

     protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
         return hasActiveInternetConnection(this.context);
     }
     protected void onPostExecute(Boolean hasActiveConnection) {
         Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Success=" + hasActiveConnection);
     }
 }
```

You would then execute it like the following:

```
NetworkUtilTask netTask = new NetworkUtilTask(context);
netTask.execute();
```

Comment: looks nice, should be the right answer. I didn't understand why using this, in an asynchronous task? could you please explain me the advantage , or the use case of this tip?

Comment: because the context is being passed to the constructor, I used `this` because there is also the Task variable `context`. Basically this just avoid ambiguity. [read up on this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Comment: I can't change protected String doInBackground(String... params)  to protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) How can I do that ? Ty !

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion , I was using the normal word "this" to speak and not ´this´ . My question was, why using an asynchronous task to check the internet connection ? thx again

Comment: @user3458008 just change it's return type

Comment: @ahmed_khan_89 my post is an attempt to answer OP's question, but you right. No need for async just to find out if you have connection